# What is the `ExceptionTable` in the output of `dis`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython, python-internals

In `python3.13`, when I try to disassemble `[i for i in range(10)]`, the result is as below:

```py
>>> import dis
>>> 
>>> dis.dis('[i for i in range(10)]')
   0           RESUME                   0

   1           LOAD_NAME                0 (range)
               PUSH_NULL
               LOAD_CONST               0 (10)
               CALL                     1
               GET_ITER
               LOAD_FAST_AND_CLEAR      0 (i)
               SWAP                     2
       L1:     BUILD_LIST               0
               SWAP                     2
       L2:     FOR_ITER                 4 (to L3)
               STORE_FAST_LOAD_FAST     0 (i, i)
               LIST_APPEND              2
               JUMP_BACKWARD            6 (to L2)
       L3:     END_FOR
       L4:     SWAP                     2
               STORE_FAST               0 (i)
               RETURN_VALUE

  --   L5:     SWAP                     2
               POP_TOP

   1           SWAP                     2
               STORE_FAST               0 (i)
               RERAISE                  0
ExceptionTable:
  L1 to L4 -> L5 [2]
```

At the end of the output, there's something `ExceptionTable`. It does not exist in the previous versions of python.

```py
Python 3.10.0b1 (default, May  4 2021, 00:00:00) [GCC 10.2.1 20201125 (Red Hat 10.2.1-9)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dis
>>> 
>>> dis.dis('[i for i in range(10)]')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x7f3d412503a0, file "<dis>", line 1>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('<listcomp>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_NAME                0 (range)
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 (10)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <listcomp> at 0x7f3d412503a0, file "<dis>", line 1>:
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                 4 (to 14)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (i)
              8 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             10 LIST_APPEND              2
             12 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            2 (to 4)
        >>   14 RETURN_VALUE
```

I can't understand what that means, also I couldn't find any document for this.

Comment: Did you look at e.g. https://docs.python.org/3.13/whatsnew/3.13.html#dis?

Comment: @jonrsharpe No, but I'll take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExceptionTable` determines *where to jump to when an exception is raised*(it was implemented in [python-3.11](/questions/tagged/python-3.11)). Prior version uses separate opcodes to handle this. *[The advantage of this approach is that entering and leaving a try block normally does not execute any code, making execution faster](https://devguide.python.org/internals/interpreter/#error-handling).*

To access this table, you can do so by accessing the `co_exceptiontable` attribute of the code object. The `ExceptionTable` representation returned by `dis` is the [result of parsing this table](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/103728dc151e3797b1b94c635b0bcd9b52c03217/Lib/dis.py#L415-L429).

```
>>> def foo():
...     c = 1 + 2
...     return c
... 
>>> 
>>> foo.__code__.co_exceptiontable
b''
>>> def foo():
...     try:
...             1/0
...     except:
...             pass
... 
>>> foo.__code__.co_exceptiontable
b'\x82\x05\x08\x00\x88\x02\x0c\x03'
>>>
>>> from dis import _parse_exception_table
>>>
>>> _parse_exception_table(foo.__code__)
[_ExceptionTableEntry(start=4, end=14, target=16, depth=0, lasti=False), _ExceptionTableEntry(start=16, end=20, target=24, depth=1, lasti=True)]
```

A detailed explanation about `ExceptionTable` is available [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/exception_handling_notes.txt). Quoting from the same link:

> [python-3.11](/questions/tagged/python-3.11) uses what is known as "**zero-cost**" exception handling.
> Prior to [python-3.11](/questions/tagged/python-3.11), exceptions were handled by a runtime stack of "blocks".
>
> In zero-cost exception handling, the cost of supporting exceptions is
> minimized. In the common case (where no exception is raised) the cost
> is reduced to zero (or close to zero). The cost of raising an
> exception is increased, but not by much.
>
> The following code:
>
> ```
> def f():
>     try:
>         g(0)
>     except:
>         return "fail"
>
> compiles as follows in 3.10:
>
>   2           0 SETUP_FINALLY            7 (to 16)
>
>   3           2 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (g)
>               4 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
>               6 CALL_NO_KW               1
>               8 POP_TOP
>              10 POP_BLOCK
>              12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
>              14 RETURN_VALUE
>
>   4     >>   16 POP_TOP
>              18 POP_TOP
>              20 POP_TOP
>
>   5          22 POP_EXCEPT
>              24 LOAD_CONST               3 ('fail')
>              26 RETURN_VALUE
> ```
>
> Note the explicit instructions to push and pop from the "block" stack:
> `SETUP_FINALLY` and `POP_BLOCK`.
>
> In 3.11, the `SETUP_FINALLY` and `POP_BLOCK` are eliminated, replaced with
> **a table to determine where to jump to when an exception is raised**.
>
> ```
>   1           0 RESUME                   0
>
>   2           2 NOP
>
>   3           4 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (g + NULL)
>              16 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
>              18 PRECALL                  1
>              22 CALL                     1
>              32 POP_TOP
>              34 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
>              36 RETURN_VALUE
>         >>   38 PUSH_EXC_INFO
>
>   4          40 POP_TOP
>
>   5          42 POP_EXCEPT
>              44 LOAD_CONST               2 ('fail')
>              46 RETURN_VALUE
>         >>   48 COPY                     3
>              50 POP_EXCEPT
>              52 RERAISE                  1
> ExceptionTable:
>   4 to 32 -> 38 [0]
>   38 to 40 -> 48 [1] lasti
> ```
>
> (Note this code is from [python-3.11](/questions/tagged/python-3.11), later versions may have slightly
> different bytecode.)
>
> **If an instruction raises an exception then its offset is used to find
> the target to jump to. For example, the `CALL` at offset `22`, falls into
> the range `4` to `32`. So, if `g()` raises an exception, then control jumps
> to offset `38`**.